# Failed to build DependencyGraph and Failed to build DependencyGraph

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Version

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "0.43.4",
"react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.1"
```

Everything worked perfect but after Install `react-native-router-flux`
all are die give too much error.

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: C:\Users\ashik\Desktop\react_apps\Friends\node_modules\react-native-router-flux\node_modules\react-native\
ackage.json collides with C:\Users\ashik\Desktop\react_apps\Friends\node_modules\react-native\package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Error: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: C:\Users\ashik\Desktop\react_apps\Friends\node_modules\react-native-router-flux\node_modules\react-native\
ackage.json collides with C:\Users\ashik\Desktop\react_apps\Friends\node_modules\react-native\package.json
```

I was already get too much question and answer as like this Error but, my React-native version and error not was same or I was not understand the solution. Please make some better solution or details for me. Also I am new in React-native and react Js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-native-router-flux` package includes its own (frozen) copy of `react-native` in order to be able to use a stable version of the `navigation-experimental` API from `react-native`. This sometimes causes collisions with the version of `react-native` being used in the project. Also, it seems the `3.38.1` release of `react-native-router-flux` causes some issues with recent versions of `react-native`. A possible solution is downgrading `react-native-router-flux` to the `3.38.0` version. Just change the line

```
 "react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.1"
```

to

```
 "react-native-router-flux": "3.38.0"
```

in your `package.json`, then delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`. The older version should not have this issue.

[reference issue in the project repo](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1803).

Comment: #Pedro_Castilho Thanks you so much ..... Really it help me so much and save my too much time Though i already try more then 2 hours . :) 
I am new in **React-native** if you give me any suggestion for  my lesson it will be great for me.